# ImageDownloadServices in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am trying below mention code for download image from server but it's not working and not giving me any error. Please suggest if any thing wrong which i used.When i am accessing URL from browser it's displaying image to me.

```
int pos; 
public void DisplayContent()
{
    f = (Form)createContainer(GlobalVariables.Theme, "ContentPageWise");
    body = (Container) findByName("Containerbody", f);
    Display_Image = new Image[Page_Details.size()];

        for(int i=0;i<Page_Details.size();i++)
        {
            Hashtable<String,String> hash_page = Page_Details.get(i);
            Log.p("imagepath:"+hash_page.get("imgPage"));
            pos=i;
            GetImagesFromserver(hash_page.get("imgPage"));
            Container Cpage = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            Label pic = new Label();
            pic.setIcon(Display_Image[i]);
            Cpage.addComponent(pic);
            body.addComponent(Cpage);
         }

}

void GetImagesFromserver(String Imagepath)
{
    //eg. url like this: http://lmsasr.gizmosupport.com/presentation/tele/internet.jpg
    ImageDownloadService imageDownloadService =
            new ImageDownloadService(Imagepath, actionListener);
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    imageDownloadService.setDisposeOnCompletion(ip.showInifiniteBlocking());
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(imageDownloadService);

}

ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {

        NetworkEvent n = (NetworkEvent) evt;
        Display_Image[pos] = ((Image)n.getMetaData());
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you run this in the debugger? Is the actionListener invoked?

Comment: Hi Almog,I checked application with break point and found that actionlistener invoked at time of form load but not when GetImageFromserver() method calls.And if i am calling GetImageFromserver() twice at that time it's giving me image. Please suggest what can i correct in code?

Comment: There are quite a few "oddities" in your code that are somewhat hard for me to grasp. First you create a form using create container which is OK but normally you should use methods from the state machine class to get everything working properly.
Then you show a progress indicator for every downloaded image which effectively means dialogs one on top of another going back to "whatever". 
If the action listener was invoked the image was downloaded, I don't understand the case of invoking later?